# How to draw on mouse click in Gtk.DrawingArea using pygi

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, programming, pygi

I am writing a small application using PyGI which will interactively draw a line on a Gtk.DrawingArea between mouse clicks. But I am unable to figure out how to draw using the cairo context at the coordinates returned by the mouse click event.

How should the drawing be handled from 'button-press-event' to draw a pattern similar to that produced by the 'draw' callback in the attached code?

```
class MyApp(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Draw on button press")
        self.set_size_request(800, 500)
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)

        self.drawing_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.drawing_area.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK) 
        self.drawing_area.connect('draw', self.on_drawing_area_draw)
        self.drawing_area.connect('button-press-event', self.on_drawing_area_button_press)
        self.drawing_area.show()
        self.add(self.drawing_area)

        self.show_all()

    def on_drawing_area_button_press(self, widget, event):
        print "Mouse clicked... at ", event.x, ", ", event.y
        # How to draw a line starting at this point on the drawing area?        
        return True

    def on_drawing_area_draw(self, drawing_area, cairo_context):
        cairo_context.move_to(50, 50)
        cairo_context.rel_line_to(0, 200)
        cairo_context.rel_line_to(200, 0)
        cairo_context.rel_line_to(0, -200)
        cairo_context.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
        cairo_context.stroke()

        return False

app = MyApp()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should do is set variables that are drawn  in the draw callback. If you want it to redraw itself you can use this to force it to:

```
drawing_area.queue_draw()
```

**Edit**: Here is an example of code you may use:

```
clicks = [];

def on_drawing_area_button_press(self, widget, event):
    print "Mouse clicked... at ", event.x, ", ", event.y
    clicks.append([event.x, event.y])
    drawing_area.queue_draw()

    return True

def on_drawing_area_draw(self, drawing_area, cairo_context):
    cairo_context.move_to(50, 50)
    for point in clicks
        cairo_context.line_to(point[0], point[1])

    cairo_context.stroke()

    return False
```